# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis at query ALTER TABLE Table_Name MODIFY Column_Name

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have a database where I want to execute this SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE PARAM_DEF MODIFY UNIT VARCHAR2(400 BYTES);
```

In SQL Server it works without any problem but in Oracle I get this error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

Why does it not work at my Oracle database?

Comment: Hi, have you try with this : ALTER TABLE PARAM_DEF MODIFY UNIT VARCHAR2(400);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [keywords for character length semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0DC7FFAA-F03F-4448-8487-F2592496A510) are `CHAR` and `BYTE` - not `BYTES`, so just correct that to:

```
ALTER TABLE PARAM_DEF MODIFY UNIT VARCHAR2(400 BYTE);
```

Demo:

```
create table param_def (unit varchar2(200 byte));

Table PARAM_DEF created.

ALTER TABLE PARAM_DEF MODIFY UNIT VARCHAR2(400 BYTE);

Table PARAM_DEF altered.

desc param_def

Name Null? Type          
---- ----- ------------- 
UNIT       VARCHAR2(400)
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `bytes` in varchar2

```
   ALTER TABLE PARAM_DEF MODIFY 
   UNIT VARCHAR2(400);
```

Comment: If the default character length semantics happen to be `CHAR` then this will have a significantly different result to the the OP's attempt, at least in multibyte environments. The OP's is limited to 400 bytes, this allows 400 characters - which maybe many more than 400 bytes between them. (This is probably safer than adding a rest the other way, but still...)

Comment: Maybe, but varchar2(..) by its semantics restricts the actual size say (400 in this case) to amount of characters in use (<=400 chars)

Comment: If you don't explicitly specify it as part of the data type then it uses the current `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` setting. By 'safer' I meant that a 400-byte value is always going to fit regardless of the column semantics; whereas a 400-char value might not fit in a 400-byte column. Even so, if the semantics are being specified as byte then it's probably for a reason, so discarding that doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: got your point @Alex Pool yeah it needs to be explicitely set as BYTE in order to restrict at levels else it ll take default `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` Thanks :)